# JsonPath - Restrict $..id Operator To Avoid Traversing Object Hierarchy

Tags: node.js, jsonpath

I was trying to extract data from a JSON object using [jsonpath package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonpath) for following JSON structure -

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "images": [
            { "id": 1,"url": "http://url1.jpg" },
            { "id": 2,"url": "http://url2.jpg" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "images": [
            { "id": 3,"url": "http://url3.jpg" },
            { "id": 4,"url": "http://url4.jpg" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "images": [
            { "id": 5,"url": "http://url5.jpg" },
            { "id": 6,"url": "http://url6.jpg" }
        ]
    }
]
```

In he above example, **`$..id`** json-path expression responds with following array -

```
[ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 6 ]
```

What I have understood from the [documentation](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) is **`$..id`** is a **`recursive descent operator`** that recursively checks for the occurrence of **`id`** field in the specified array.

This is where I get the problem. I need an expression that simply checks for **`id`** in current object and avoids traversing recursively in **`images`** array.

So the expected output is -

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I tried [JSONPath Online Evaluator](https://jsonpath.com/) to verify the results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation of **jsonpath** they include
..  as Recursive descendant operator;
 JSONPath borrows this syntax from E4X

$..* is used when you need to search in All memebers of JSON Structure.

So, if you want restrict the filter at the child you want you need to use $.*.
 [Here are the syntax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Comiw.jpg)

The code you want is:-

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var jp = require('jsonpath');

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('data.json');
let data = JSON.parse(rawdata);


var id = jp.query(data,'$.*.id');

console.log(id);
```

Output is 
[1,2,3]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `*` operator which restricts the filter at the level you need.

To get it to do the thing that you want you would use:

`$.*.id`

and that will give you the output of:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```

But let's say you want the `image` specific `id` you would use:

`$.*.images.*.id`

which would give you the output of:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
]
```